# How do I stop water from leaking through the bottom of my shed walls when it rains?

Tags: drainage, shed

I have a shed that was built on a low foundation so that when it rains water builds up against it and water tends to flow in between the concrete and the bottom of the wall and now there's mold growing inside. Is there something I can do? I've tried spraying expanding foam between the concrete and the frame but it still leaks.

Comment: You could try putting gutters/drains around the edge of the shed

Comment: Not seeing the shed it's kind of hard to say for sure. But, some options are: jack it up and raise foundation, dig a trench beside shed sloped away, put a french drain beside shed sloped away.

Comment: I was considering the ditch .. The drive way leads right to it and its gravel and sloping towards the shed instead of away from it so the gutters wont really work since the water runs from the driveway down to the front door..